# Spam email sent from my noreply@domain.com account

Tags: spam

A spam email is being sent from my default email(noreply@mydomain.com) to all the subscriber. What may have caused this and how could I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Hello and welcome on WPSE. There is not really a direct answer for that question as it, because it can be done from the outside without your knowledge that it is done.  Maybe reading answers about such from [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/415533/how-to-stop-people-from-using-my-domain-to-send-spam) helps you a little more then I could give in an answer..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your site has not been compromised, and that there are not unknown admin-level user accounts, then this could just be a case of mail spoofing. (Where a person places your email address as the 'from', but the email is really being sent by an external process.)

I'd change all credentials (hosting, FTP, admin-level users). Then look for unauthorized admin-level users. I might also create a new admin-level user with a strong password, log in as that user, then change the old admin user to a lower level (subscriber, for instance).

I might also look for evidence of site compromise. Update everything (WP via the Admin, Update screen, themes/plugins manually via FTP). Then look at all folders for files that shouldn't be there (they will have different timestamps because you updated everything). Also check the htaccess file.

And check generated pages page source for unusual code. I created a process to de-hack a site [here](https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/), perhaps that would be useful to you. (There are many googles/bings/ducks about that subject also.)